# Why is my text splitting at lower resolutions?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

So I have this card that looks like this

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3">
          <img width="150" heigth="150" class="img-fluid " src="https://widgetwhats.com/app/uploads/2019/11/free-profile-photo-whatsapp-4.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-10 col-sm-9 text-left pr-0">
          <span style="font-weight: lighter; font-size:22px;">USERNAME</span>

          <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-9 col-xs-5">
            <span class=" col-md-4 col-xs-4" style="font-weight: lighter; font-size:12px;">100 POSTS</span>
            <span class="col-md-5 col-xs-4" style="font-weight: lighter; font-size:12px;">100 FOLLOWERS</span>
            <span class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 " style="font-weight: lighter; font-size:12px;">100 FOLLOWING</span>
            <span class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 " style="font-weight: lighter; font-size:12px;">Phone: 100</span>
            <span class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 " style="font-weight: lighter; font-size:12px;">Email: 100</span>
          </div>
          <div class="mb-1 mt-1">
            <span style="font-weight: bold; font-size:12px;">More Text</span>
          </div>

          <div>
            <span style="font-weight: normal; font-size:12px; -webkit-line-clamp: 3; text-overflow: ellipsis; -webkit-box-orient: vertical; display: -webkit-box; overflow: hidden;">
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus molestie at urna id faucibus. Proin facilisis lectus ac luctus gravida. Phasellus posuere nec mauris ac hendrerit. Curabitur venenatis et augue id dignissim. Curabitur vitae nunc dignissim, ultricies lorem quis, malesuada odio. In molestie metus nec ligula finibus, sed placerat odio ornare. In eu faucibus elit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Vestibulum efficitur turpis eu iaculis maximus. Proin pharetra congue risus quis rhoncus.
                            </span>
          </div>

        </div>
        <div class="col-12 pr-0 mt-3">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary float-right mr-2">Extract</button>
        </div>

      </div>
```

And it works just fine, until I get down to a lower resolution and it starts cutting the text off for some reason as shown here

[image]

is there no way to maybe align them to the left and make them stack vertically?

Comment: Did you get the expected results?

Answer (score 1):

Is this how you were expecting the results to be -

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2">
          <img width="150" heigth="150" class="img-fluid " src="https://widgetwhats.com/app/uploads/2019/11/free-profile-photo-whatsapp-4.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-10 col-sm-12 text-left pr-0">
          <span style="font-weight: lighter; font-size:22px;">USERNAME</span>

          <div class="row col-lg-10 col-md-9 col-sm-12">
            <span class=" col-md-5 col-sm-6" style="font-weight: lighter; font-size:12px;">100 POSTS</span>
            <span class="col-md-5 col-sm-6" style="font-weight: lighter; font-size:12px;">100 FOLLOWERS</span>
            <span class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 " style="font-weight: lighter; font-size:12px;">100 FOLLOWING</span>
            <span class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 " style="font-weight: lighter; font-size:12px;">Phone: 100</span>
            <span class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 " style="font-weight: lighter; font-size:12px;">Email: 100</span>
          </div>
          <div class="mb-1 mt-1">
            <span style="font-weight: bold; font-size:12px;">More Text</span>
          </div>

          <div>
            <span style="font-weight: normal; font-size:12px; -webkit-line-clamp: 3; text-overflow: ellipsis; -webkit-box-orient: vertical; display: -webkit-box; overflow: hidden;">
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus molestie at urna id faucibus. Proin facilisis lectus ac luctus gravida. Phasellus posuere nec mauris ac hendrerit. Curabitur venenatis et augue id dignissim. Curabitur vitae nunc dignissim, ultricies lorem quis, malesuada odio. In molestie metus nec ligula finibus, sed placerat odio ornare. In eu faucibus elit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Vestibulum efficitur turpis eu iaculis maximus. Proin pharetra congue risus quis rhoncus.
                            </span>
          </div>

        </div>
        <div class="col-12 pr-0 mt-3">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary float-right mr-2">Extract</button>
        </div>

      </div>
```

See if this helps !  ;)